# Storing list into dictionary from excel- part 2

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary, store

I have a list and I want to convert it into expected dictionary output.

list is:

```
[['Nodeb_IN_New',107,'class-default',['h10'],['h1'],[7],'dscp-fc-map',['ef']],[",","['h11'],['h2'],[5],'dscp-fc-map',['af41']],[",",",['l12','l13','l14'],['l1'],[4],'dscp-fc-map',['af11','af21','af31']],['Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN','102',",['h15','h16'],['h1'],[7],'dscp-fc-map',['ef','nc1']]]
```

and expected dictionary output is:

```
res1= {'Nodeb_IN_New':{'policy_id':107,'default':'class-default','mplsa':['h10','h11','l12','l13','l14'],'mpls':['h1','h2','l1'],'qos':[7,5,4],'nokia':'dscp-fc-map','dscp':['ef','af41,'af11','af21','af31']},'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN':{'policy_id':'102',default':",'mplsa':['h15','h16'],'mpls':['h1'],'qos':[7],'nokia':'dscp-fc-map','dscp':['ef','nc1']}}
```

This is the excel from where I am maiking the list:

[image: excel sheet]

if list[0] means first column is empty then don't read dscp_fc_map
Please help with the code.

Comment: Can you share a text version of the Excel data instead of a picture?

Comment: Nodeb_IN_New 107 class-default mobility-platinum h10 h1 7 dscp-fc-map ['ef']
   mobility-gold-new h11 h2 5 dscp-fc-map ['af41']
   mobility-silver-new l12 l13 l14 l1 4 dscp-fc-map ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']
Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN 102  Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum h15 h16 h1 7 dscp-fc-map ['ef', 'nc1']

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can get you need to convert list of lists to dict where keys are first items in each of innner list and value is dict with fixed keys and values from second to last elements of inner list. It's pretty easy in python:

```
lst = [
  ['key1', 'val1', 'val2', ['complex', 'val']], 
  ['key2', 'val21', 'val22', ['complex2', 'val2']] 
]

# First step
# result = {
#   l[0]: l[1:] for l in lst
# }

# Second step
# dict(zip(['header1', 'header2', 'header3'], l))
#

# Combined
result = {
  l[0]: dict(zip(['key11', 'key12', 'complexkey'], l[1:])) for l in lst
}
```

which gives:

```
result = 
{
 'key1': {'key11': 'val1',  'key12': 'val2',  'complexkey': ['complex', 'val']  },
 'key2': {'key11': 'val21', 'key12': 'val22', 'complexkey': ['complex2', 'val2']}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for, if not, kindly elaborate your question.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'Check.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding='utf-16')
df.rename( index={0:'policy_id', 1: 'default'...........}, inplace = True)
df = df.to_dict()
```